# How can I read a text file and decode it in UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am reading this file with stopwords: https://github.com/solariz/german_stopwords/blob/master/german_stopwords_plain.txt with Python.

This is my code:

```
import csv

with open('German_Stopwords.txt','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
```

But when I read it with Python it is not correct UTF-8 anymore.
As other threads suggested I wrote

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

At the top of the file, but it didnt help.
I am using Python 3.

Comment: Python 2.x or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: If you really need to, add `encoding='utf-8'` to `open`.

Comment: `open(..., encoding='utf-8')`…?!